# React project won't start on windows command prompt with error in lifecycle, WSL Bash is good

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to start without error project in Windows command prompt. When i started it with Windows comand prompt it throw error. But in my operation system i have installed ubuntu subsystem from windows store. Maybe this fact contribute to fail. When i start project in Ubuntu terminal(WSL Bash) it runs correctly without errors. Ok, that was i did with Windows command prompt. First i run `npm i` with my `package.json` below.

```
{
  "name": "star-db",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Install was good. But when i start my project with `npm start` in Windows command prompt it crashes with error below.

```
D:\Мои проекты, наработки\React\second-project>npm start

> star-db@0.1.0 start D:\Мои проекты, наработки\React\second-project
> react-scripts start
Starting the development server...
Compiled successfully!

You can now view star-db in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.103:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.



#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0000001F024FE030npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! star-db@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the star-db@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vsevo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-28T02_27_49_910Z-debug.log
```

Text log file below:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle star-db@0.1.0~prestart: star-db@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle star-db@0.1.0~start: star-db@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle star-db@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle star-db@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\vsevo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Мои проекты, наработки\React\second-project\node_modules\.bin;C:\Go\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Users\vsevo\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;D:\MatLab\runtime\win64;D:\MatLab\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;D:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_211;C:\Program Files\WSO2\API Manager\2.6.0\\bin;%NVM_HOME%;%NVM_SYMLINK%;C:\Users\vsevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;D:\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\vsevo\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_211;C:\Users\vsevo\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs
9 verbose lifecycle star-db@0.1.0~start: CWD: D:\Мои проекты, наработки\React\second-project
10 silly lifecycle star-db@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle star-db@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null
12 info lifecycle star-db@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: star-db@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vsevo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vsevo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
14 verbose pkgid star-db@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\Мои проекты, наработки\React\second-project
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.0.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225477
22 error star-db@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 3221225477
23 error Failed at the star-db@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225477, true ]
```

Node version is 12.0.0
npm version is 6.9.0

Comment: after updating node problem wasn't solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem but it has been fixed with the new nodejs version (12.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

I think that upgrading node will help but deleting all the files associated with `node`, `npm`, their cashes, etc helps me.